# Prove that if $f(1) = 0$, then $f(x) = 0$ for every $x\in R $

Tags: analysis

Let $R$ and $S$ be rings with unity, and $f : R\to  S$ a ring homomorphism. Assume $S$ is an integral domain. Prove that if $f(1) = 0$, then $f(x) = 0$ for every $x \in  R $.

It looks like I am trying to define the kernel of $f$ where $1$ is known to be in the kernel.

I am a little confused because why can't I just say the definition of a kernel of a function since I know that there exists a ring homomorphism?

Suggestions are welcome.

Comment: $I = {\rm ker}\ f\,$ is an ideal, so $\,1\in I\ \Rightarrow\  r\cdot 1\in I,\,\ \forall r\in R\ \Rightarrow\ I = R\ \ $

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider
$$
f(x)=f(1x)=f(1)f(x)=\dots
$$

Note that the fact that $S$ is a domain is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

$f(x) = f(x\cdot 1) = f(x)\cdot f(1) = f(x)\cdot 0 = 0$

Comment: I was not looking for a give away but thank you for posting anyway.